# I would like to put more than one website in a single html file

Tags: html, hyperlink, href

I want to have a couple html websites in a single file. Is this possible?

Comment: You might want to reword this to describe your intentions.  What are you actually trying to accomplish here?  Is this just a curiosity or do you actually have a use-case where this seems like a good idea? Why would you desire to handle it this way?  Do you plan to use server-side languages or is everything static HTML?

Answer (score 1):

A website is not just an html "page".

An html **file** represents the document structure of one page.

Theoretically, saying that you want to represent multiple websites on one html file is like saying that you want to write different documents (your tax files, a book, a ticket for a movie, etc) based on one single template.

While theoretically you can dinamically change the structure of such a document, there is absolutely no point in doing so.

*HTML describes the structure of Web pages using markup*.

So why would you use a single HTML file to represent different web pages?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but you can't. It's not possible. Why would you even do it?
The only thing that comes into my mind is to use `<embed>`tag, for ex. But it's probably not what you rly want

Answer (score 0):

You must be more specific. The question is vague. In general you can write a code that can change dynamically the website appearance after inputs/actions from the users. For example a JavaScript code that shows/hides something (or the complete website) as long as the mouse is over an element or select/deselect an element. It all can be in a single html document (html5, css3, JavaScript/JQuery).